# XMLStreamReader how to work with nested elements of same type

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I'm working with the XMLStreamReader and parsing the following XML:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <attribute>level0</attribute>
        <element>
            <attribute>level1</attribute>
            <element>
                <attribute>level2</attribute>
            </element>
        </element>
    </element>
</root>
```

I'm building out my XMLStreamReader:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
```

Unfortunately, when I get to the first closing element tag with `reader.next();`, I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[7,14]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Is there a way to override the default behavior of the XMLStreamReader to get around with this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code I am working with:

```
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String document = value.toString();
    System.out.println("'" + document + "'");
    try {
        XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(document.getBytes()));
        String propertyName = "";
        String propertyValue = "";
        String currentElement = "";
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            int code = reader.next();
            switch (code) {
            case START_ELEMENT:
                currentElement = reader.getLocalName();
                break;
            case CHARACTERS:
                if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("element")) {
                    propertyName += reader.getText();
                } else if (currentElement.equalsIgnoreCase("attribute")) {
                    propertyValue += reader.getText();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        context.write(new Text(propertyName.trim()), new Text(propertyValue.trim()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your XML is probably not well-formed, I guess the real XML document is not what you put in your post, as that looks okay.

Comment: @biziclop I've tested with that exact XML. The error it is giving is valid... the reader throws it because it gets to a closing tag for the 3rd element and thinks I am trying to close the 1st element. What I want to know, is there a way around this?

Comment: It absolutely certainly doesn't do that. There's either something wrong in your XML or your code (which you haven't included in your question).

Comment: @biziclop see edit for code. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the example XML document and/or the StAX parser as can be checked with this code:

```
@Test
public void testSO_31815379() throws XMLStreamException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final String xml = 
        "<root>\n" +
        "    <element>\n" +
        "        <attribute>level0</attribute>\n" +
        "        <element>\n" +
        "            <attribute>level1</attribute>\n" +
        "            <element>\n" +
        "                <attribute>level2</attribute>\n" +
        "            </element>\n" +
        "        </element>\n" +
        "    </element>\n" +
        "</root>";

    final XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
        .createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    LOG.info("Using XMLStreamReader implementation: %s", reader.getClass().getName());

    reader.require(XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT, null, null);
    int event;
    while ((event = reader.next()) != XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {
        LOG.info(StaxUtils.eventDescription(reader));
    }
    reader.require(XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT, null, null);
    reader.close();
}
```

Output (`StaxUtils.eventDescription` is a custom helper method)

```
Using XMLStreamReader implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl
START_ELEMENT<{}root>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}attribute>
CHARACTERS='level0'
END_ELEMENT<attribute>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}attribute>
CHARACTERS='level1'
END_ELEMENT<attribute>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
START_ELEMENT<{}attribute>
CHARACTERS='level2'
END_ELEMENT<attribute>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
END_ELEMENT<element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
END_ELEMENT<element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
END_ELEMENT<element>
CHARACTERS=<whitespace>
END_ELEMENT<root>
```

Comment: thanks but this does not work. I get the following error if I try and get the text of the element: `Message: elementGetText() function expects text only elment but START_ELEMENT was encountered.`

Comment: The code works as demonstrated :) If you need the text from an element, you have to call `reader#getText()` (or related function) when the cursor is at an `CHARACTERS` event (see example output, all data is shown!). We can better help you if you post the code that is troublesome.

Comment: got your code to work. Posted my troublesome code. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Bonus tips: 1) *always* use a `default` clause in your `switch` statement. If working with `XMLStreamReader`, you should use a stack or deque to keep track of the elements visited.

Comment: Turns out it was malformed xml... the function sending in the XML was stripping off the final element tag. Thanks fro the help.